# Entity Model, grouping models in one model file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model

I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MyTestWebsite.Models
{
    public class Page
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int AuthorUserId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public bool Hidden { get; set; }
    }

    public class PageState
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyTestWebsiteDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Page> Pages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PageState> PageStates { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I went to create a controller for Page and I found the model structure.. no problems.

This is, I need another model called PageState and my model list does not show this second model.

Is it usual to have a heck load of models.... regardless of them being linked in some way?

Do I just add a model on its own called PageState?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it usual to have a heck load of models

Yes, they are called view models. Each view should have a specific view model. It's perfectly normal to have many view models if you have many views. A view model could aggregate one or more of your EF domain models.

Comment: Can you group these together in folders for organisational purposes considering my controller creator does not recognise the PageState model as it's not its own class?

Comment: Is it okay to have one database with all your models inside?

Comment: Surely I only want one DBContext and have all my models working through this... This means I only need one connection in web.config? So confused ^_^... Use to PHP and MySQL

Comment: @JamesT I think you say "model" where you mean "class". Yes, the DbContext is a C# representation of your tables in the database, so it usually contains a lot of classes, that are related by associations (navigation properties).